# Apache is not able to read my .css files

Tags: css, linux, apache

I have a LAMP setup on my Linux Mint machine and everytime I try to open an index file which has some css styling done in an external file, my browser can't show the css styling and gives me an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

and from the apache error log:

```
[Sun Oct 13 20:04:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /blog/js/bootstrap.js denied, referer: http://localhost/blog/index.php
```

Now, I know that it has something to do with permissions, but I can't really seem to get over it. I tried to do `chmod 777 folder` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only you need to set the correct permissions for the folder, but also for the file you are talking about. Please issue:

```
chmod 0644 /path/to/blog/js/bootstrap.js
```

Or any other permissions mode that will let Apache access the file.

Comment: Tried aswell, but isn't working.

Comment: The error message refers to a JS file. You need to set the correct permission on that. Also make sure that it is located *inside* the web root.

Comment: Apache's own permission problems don't cause 403s, they cause 404s. 403 is caused by the Apache configuration denying access, not the file system.

Comment: @EJP Nope. The problem is not necessary with the config file: read the first paragraph of https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that the problem is a javascript file, not a css file.

Also, it's most likely that it is your Apache configuration and not your file permissions that are causing Apache to deny access. Apache, out of the  box, in most Linux distributions, is configured to restrict access to the file system except where the configuration indicates that it is permitted.

Finally, **setting permissions to 777 is never the answer**. Please change them back to something reasonable.

Comment: There are multiple css files and some js files, I encounter the same problem with everyone of them, I just explained what happens with that one file.

Comment: Apache config seems ok to me aswell: [link](http://pastebin.com/b9zGDwxK)